# Powershell -contains operator

Tags: powershell

I am working to get something working.  I am trying to build a script to create user accounts and I want to verify that they don't already exist in the system.  Here is my code snippet.

```
#Check if users exist
$ObjOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
$colUsers = ($objComputer.psbase.children | Where-Object {$_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "User"} | Select-Object -expand Name)
$blnFound = $colUsers -contains $userin -or $userout
if ($blnFound) {"The user exists"}
else {"Creating user account"}
```

The issue I am having is that no matter what the array contains, the $blnfound variable comes back as true so long as I am using the -or operator.  If I test it one at a time, without the -or, both come back as false.

Is there a different way that I should be doing this?

Comment: probably an issue with order of operations try `$colUsers -contains $userin -or $colUsers -contains $userout`

Answer (score 1):

Red Alert nailed it.  Order of operations.

```
$colUsers -contains $userin -or $colUsers -contains $userout
```